# wlCommonInit() not called when application is opened from a notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, mobile-application

If the application is not started and the request to open the application comes from a APNS message, wlCommonInit() in main.js never gets called.

The strange part is, when I add an `alert("xxx...");` message in initOptions.js  before the MobileFirst generated (`if(WL.Client.getEnvironment()...` statement),   `wlCommonInit()` in main.js gets called and everything functions correctly.

The code that controls this flow appears to be worklight.js.
If the application is already running in the background, the application get's the focus correctly, even without the `alert("xxx...");` to initOptions.js.

Current Environment:

- iPhone 5 with iOS 9.2.1(13D15) - for testing
- Xcode 7.2(7C68)
- MobileFirst 7.1.0.00-20151227-1725

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you saying that , if the application is not running and tapping the notification in the notification center, launches the application but does not execute wlCommonInit() ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Also, when the push notification message comes in, slide the message to the right, then log into the iPhone. It should open the application.

Comment: @RaymondYee, If you're doing this with the sample push notifications provided as part of the mfp tutorials. Is it also failing the same way?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work correctly with the push notifications sample provided with the tutorial. Please try it on your end as well and compare the implementation.